# Draw panel on a web site?

Tags: drawing

What is best way for making a draw panel in a web page. I would like to know how to develop something very simple,for example little panel where users can draw a signature.

This is great example [drawhere.com](http://drawhere.com), but I need something way simpler.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whilst Zifre's answer is valid in one sense, I would be very weary of the <canvas> tag, at least at the moment, due to there not being fantastic support for it (as many browsers don't yet fully support HTML5).

Some browsers support it (most notably Firefox and anything running on Webkit), but swathes of others don't (especially older browsers).  It's perhaps better to go for a *more* universal solution (though, by no means completely universal), and use something *like* Flash.

Comment: Yes, for a moment I was amazed how simple it could be but then I saw that even IE7 does not have support for canvas. Thanks..

Comment: Just another reason not to use IE! Not that any technologically educated people really do...

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this is probably with the `<canvas>` tag and some JavaScript. [Here](http://www.damonkohler.com/2008/12/javascript-painting-with-canvas.html) is a really simple example to get you started. You can add more functions for things like circles, boxes, etc.

I'm sure somebody has already made something like this that you could use, but I couldn't find any.